# How is something like 30.seconds.ago implemented?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I found this question [here](https://github.com/afeld/rails_interview_questions).

And really curious to know the technical explanation of how something like `30.seconds.ago` is implemented in Rails.

Method chaining? `Numeric` usage as per:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-seconds .

What else?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb#L19-L24) is the implementation of the `seconds`:

```
  def seconds
    ActiveSupport::Duration.new(self, [[:seconds, self]])
  end
```

And, [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L110-L115) is the implementation of the `ago`:

```
# Calculates a new Time or Date that is as far in the past
# as this Duration represents.
def ago(time = ::Time.current)
  sum(-1, time)
end
```

And, [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/activesupport/lib/active_support/duration.rb#L137-L149) is the implementation of the `sum` method that's used inside the `ago`:

```
  def sum(sign, time = ::Time.current) #:nodoc:
    parts.inject(time) do |t,(type,number)|
      if t.acts_like?(:time) || t.acts_like?(:date)
        if type == :seconds
          t.since(sign * number)
        else
          t.advance(type => sign * number)
        end
      else
        raise ::ArgumentError, "expected a time or date, got #{time.inspect}"
      end
    end
  end
```

To understand it fully, you should follow the method calls and look for their implementations in the Rails source code like I showed you just now.

One easy way to find a method definition inside Rails code base is to use `source_location` in your Rails console:

```
> 30.method(:seconds).source_location
# => ["/Users/rislam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb", 19]
> 30.seconds.method(:ago).source_location
# => ["/Users/rislam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/duration.rb", 108]
```